# Lambdas and Folds (Left and Right)

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming

I really don't understand code

```
myReverse'' :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse'' xs = foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id xs []
```

In case:

- empty mapping to [] <---- accumulator
- id mapping to fID (func id)
- x is first element of xs (list)

Can i sort/change the postion of agruments "id xs []" ?

```
myReverse'' xs = foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) xs id []
```

I have read a book yesterday http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#lambdas

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool  
elem' y ys = foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

The explanation is understandable to me.

> the left fold's binary function has the accumulator as the first parameter and the current value as the second one (so \acc x -> ...)

or I can write as

```
elem' :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem' y ys = foldr (\x acc -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

Anyone, can help/guide/explain me ? 
 
Many thanks!

Comment: "Can i sort/change the postion of agruments "id xs []" ?" Can you clarify your question? It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I like to understand these "reverse list with `foldr`" problems is to split it into pieces, and apply the lesson of ["Foldr is made of monoids"](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/foldr-is-made-of-monoids/).  Don't worry, this isn't as scary as it sounds.

First, let's note that `reverse` can be implemented this way:

```
my_reverse xs = foldl (flip (:)) xs []
```

This is the first simplification to our problem: if we can figure out how to write `foldl` in terms of `foldr`, then we can plug that solution into `my_reverse` to and be done with it.

Now, the standard type signature for `foldr` is this:

```
foldr :: (a -> r -> r) -> r -> [a] -> r
```

But the order of the arguments doesn't really matter, so let's rearrange things this way (throwing in a few implicit parentheses as well), and we'll compare it with `map`:

```
my_foldr :: (a -> (r -> r)) -> [a] -> (r -> r)
map      :: (a -> b       ) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Once you see this correspondence, it's not hard to see that we can write `my_foldr` this way:

```
my_foldr :: (a -> (r -> r)) -> [a] -> (r -> r)
my_foldr f as = compose (map f as)
  where compose :: [r -> r] -> (r -> r)
        compose = foldr (.) id
```

Think of this in the following way:

1. The `map` operation is converting each element of the list into a "step" of the transformation that we apply to the `r` values.
2. The `compose` function takes the resulting list of "steps" and wires them all together, using the `.` operator.

And now the trick is that we can write a `foldl` counterpart with a small change:

```
my_foldl :: (a -> (r -> r)) -> [a] -> (r -> r)
my_foldl f as = compose (map f as)
    where compose :: [r -> r] -> (r -> r)
          compose = foldr (flip (.)) id

{- Example:
>>>  my_foldl (:) [1..3] []
[3,2,1]
-}
```

All I did was change `(.)` to `flip (.)`!  And note that `my_foldl` is written in terms of `map` and `foldr`... but `map` can be rewritten in terms of `foldr` as well:

```
my_map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
my_map f = foldr (\a bs -> f a : bs) []
```

So we've ended up with a solution that's different and longer than the one you're trying to understand, but hopefully it's illuminating.

Comment: I think `my_reverse xs = foldl (flip (:)) [] xs`, with `[] xs` at the end, not `... xs []`

Answer (score 1):

The crucial thing is how this work with *difference lists*. Let's write out some explicit conversions:

```
type DList a = [a]->[a]

emptyDList :: Dlist a
emptyDList = id

fromDList :: DList a -> [a]
fromDList f = f []

myReverse'' :: ∀ a . [a] -> [a]
myReverse'' xs = fromDList $ foldr revCons emptyDList xs 
 where revCons :: a -> DList a -> DList a
       revCons x fId empty = fId $ x : empty
```

Note that `revCons` has three arguments, though its signature actually suggests only two: difference lists are really a function type, but you can think of these functions as an abstract optimised representation for concrete lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
Prelude :t \x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)
```

You will get:

```
\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty) :: a -> ([a] -> t) -> [a] -> t
```

This function type here is equivalent to:

```
a -> ([a] -> t) -> ([a] -> t)
```

which means a function (binary function) that takes two arguments (the second argument is a function i.e. `[a] -> t`) and returns a function (i.e. `[a] -> t`).

This binary function matches the first argument that `foldr` takes (i.e. `a -> b -> b`).

In other words, `foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty))` takes two arguments: a function and a list and returns a function.

```
Prelude> :t foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty))
foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty))
  :: ([a] -> t) -> [a] -> [a] -> t
```

Take this example: `foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id [1, 2, 3]`.

Step 1: `3` and `id` are passed to the anonymous binary function as arguments. A function like `\empty -> id (3 : empty)` is returned as the new accumulator value.

Step 2: `2` and `\empty -> id (3 : empty)` are passed to the anonymous binary function. And `\empty -> id (3 : (2 : empty))` is returned.

Step 3: `1` and `\empty -> id (3 : (2 : empty))` are passed to the anonymous binary function. And `\empty -> id (3 : (2 : (1 : empty)))` is returned.

So `foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id [1, 2, 3]` produces a function like `\empty -> id (3 : (2 : (1 : empty)))`.

If you apply `\empty -> id (3 : (2 : (1 : empty)))` to `[]`, then it will give you `[3, 2, 1]`.

This means `foldr (\x fId empty -> fId (x : empty)) id [1, 2, 3] []` produces `[3, 2, 1]`.